# "OCR" characters/short sequences of text/numbers

Tags: c#, ocr, pixel

here is my problem: I have to identify numbers (such as 853 / 52) and some text (containing around 8 letters of the alphabet) from a bitmap and i have to do that really fast.

Tesseract does the trick, but its execution time is a bit too slow for my liking. Since i have such a limited amount of characters that are always of the same font size and same font, i was thinking i could just extract them all and build a lookup table for certain characteristics of one character.

Yet to achieve this i would have to be able to "split" up a bitmap containing lets say 853 into its individual characters (kinda box them as some of those OCR trainers do).

Unfortunately i have no idea, how to start boxing/seperating them.. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Recognizing patterns is easy for humans but not so easy for machines. I'm not sure if limiting expected shapes would provide enough of a speed up. Maybe this is of interest to you: [Large pattern recognition system using multi neural networks](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/376798/Large-pattern-recognition-system-using-multi-neura)

Comment: Could you please post a sample image here?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the arictle. 
I kinda solved half my problem.. If i use Aforge i can run them through a set of filters, in my case i increase contrast before i grayscale and binarize, and then run blob extraction on them, which allows me to chop up the picture. Now i have a clean set of character images that i will "only" have to match against comparitve ones.